# Does the logarithm of matrices with determinant -1 exist?

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I found on the book that $log(A)$ (where log(A) = $\sum_{i=1}^\infty (-1)^{i-1}(A-I)^i/i$) does not exist if $det(A)=-1$, is there any proof for that?

A useful information is that $log(A)$ converges if every entry of $A-I$ smaller than $1/n$ in magnitude.

Comment: This question needs quite a bit more context.  How are you defining the logarithm of a matrix? via a power series?  What does it mean to say that $\log(A)$ doesn't exist?  that the power series fails to converge?  Which book are you reading from?  can you please provide a citation, complete with a page number?

Comment: And are you talking about real logarithms?  If you are prepared to say in the complex numbers that $\log(-1)=i\pi (2n+1)$ or something similar then you can have $\log(A)$ where $\det(A)=-1$

Comment: Your series for $\log(A)$ looks like what I usually call $\exp(A)$.

Comment: I fixed the definition of log thanks for your comments.

Comment: What is $n$ in your last remark?

Comment: Can ***A*** have [complex eigenvalues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix)?